# Is there a counter for tumblr share button?

Tags: api, jsonp, tumblr

I want to add tumblr share button on my blog and I am wondering is there any way to know how many times my article was shared? I've search though the Tumblr API and Internet but haven't found any answer.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK if you generated the button from this page: http://www.tumblr.com/buttons the closest your going to get to a figure is `{{NoteCount}}`. A **share** on Tumblr is technically a reblog.

Sadly `{{NoteCount}}` is a combination of Likes and Reblogs. More information here: http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#notes

Comment: yes, but this is in context of my blog... so I should create a blog on tumblr post there every entry I want to share later and then on my page use tumblr link in share button?

Comment: I don't quiet understand the comment. Tumblr 'share' is for sharing a link to your article on another Tumblr site. Article A has a 'share button'. Site B reads Article A, and clicks 'share button'. Site B now has a link post on its site, linking to Article A.

Comment: Yes, but Article A doesn't have to be on Tumblr and I would like to count how many Tumblr bloggers shared my article to their Blogs.

Comment: Correct Article A doesn't have to be on Tumblr. Afaik if I posted a link to Article A (Offsite) on my Tumblr and you posted a link to Article A on your Tumblr, there isn't a way to get a count of 2. The only count you could get is if you rebloged my initial link to Article A on to your Tumblr. Even then its still not accurate.